# Win32, How can I set PROCESS_TERMINATE and SYNCHRONIZE for lpProcessAttributes and have them inherit to child processes?

Tags: winapi

If I make the Win32 API calls below:

How can I set PROCESS_TERMINATE and SYNCHRONIZE for lpProcessAttributes and have them **inherit to child processes** so I can terminate all child processes?

```
    PROCESS_INFORMATION process_info;
    STARTUPINFO startup_info;

    ZeroMemory(&process_info, sizeof(PROCESS_INFORMATION));
    ZeroMemory(&startup_info, sizeof(STARTUPINFO));

    SetLastError(0);

    BOOL bSuccess = CreateProcess(
    /*[in, optional]      LPCSTR                lpApplicationName    */ nullptr,
    /*[in, out, optional] LPSTR                 lpCommandLine        */
    "powershell -command dir C:\\windows -recurse",
    /*[in, optional]      LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpProcessAttributes  */ nullptr,
    /*[in, optional]      LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpThreadAttributes   */ nullptr,
    /*[in]                BOOL                  bInheritHandles      */ TRUE,
    /*[in]                DWORD                 dwCreationFlags      */ 0,
    /*[in, optional]      LPVOID                lpEnvironment        */ nullptr,
    /*[in, optional]      LPCSTR                lpCurrentDirectory   */ "C:\\",
    /*[in]                LPSTARTUPINFOA        lpStartupInfo        */ &startup_info,
    /*[out]               LPPROCESS_INFORMATION lpProcessInformation */ &process_info
    );


    TerminateProcess(process_info.hProcess, 0);

    // 500 ms timeout; use INFINITE for no timeout
    const DWORD result = WaitForSingleObject(
                            process_info.hProcess, 500);
    if (result == WAIT_OBJECT_0) {
        // Success
    }  
    else {
        // Timed out or an error occurred
    }

    CloseHandle(process_info.hProcess);
    CloseHandle(process_info.hThread);
```

Comment: `PROCESS_TERMINATE` and `SYNCHRONIZE` this is access rights. it set on `HANDLE` only and `SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES` here unrelated. and both `PROCESS_TERMINATE` and `SYNCHRONIZE` will be set on `process_info.hProcess`. but you can not inherit handle which yet not created (`process_info.hProcess`). *so I can terminate all child processes* use for this job object (assign new process to job (with `JOB_OBJECT_LIMIT_KILL_ON_JOB_CLOSE` and duplicate this job handle to new process)

Comment: Thanks.  But, specifically how do you set PROCESS_TERMINATE on the handle?   It needs to be an object of type LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES not DWORD define from a header like PROCESS_TERMINATE.

Answer (score 1):

According to the Doc:[Process Security and Access Rights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/process-security-and-access-rights)

> The handle returned by the CreateProcess function has
> PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS access to the process object.

According to the Doc:[TerminateProcess function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-terminateprocess)

> A handle to the process to be terminated.
>
> The handle must have the PROCESS_TERMINATE access right.

As far as I'm concerned, the handle return by CreateProcess should have necessary and sufficient access-rights to allow killing the process using TerminateProcess.

**terminate all child processes**

If you wang to terminate all child processes,I suggest you could try to use `JOB_OBJECT_LIMIT_KILL_ON_JOB_CLOSE`.

For more details, I suggest you could refer to the Bilog:[Destroying all child processes (and grandchildren) when the parent exits](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20131209-00/?p=2433)

Comment: @pico Have you got any updates? If your case has been solved, please help to mark answers. If not, just feel free to contact us. Your understanding and cooperation will be grateful.